# Averaging rows by multiple column variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, average, bar-chart, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a multiple bar chart of my data, depicting the mean of avgct for each region with error bars using ggplot2.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
gregion lregion   avgct
1          e      1.146
1          e      0.947
2          e      0.908    
3          e      1.167
1          t      1.225   
2          t      1.058
2          t      2.436
3          t      0.679
```

So far I have managed to create this graph, but it seems to be plotting the maximum values for avgct not the mean and therefore I cannot create error bars.

[image]

I think I need to calculate the mean of avgct by gregion and lregion so that I have an average value of avgct for each region, like this:

```
gregion lregion   mean(avgct)   
1          e      1.047 
2          e      0.908 
3          e      1.167
1          t      1.225 
2          t      1.747
3          t      0.679
```

If anyone can help me with this so that I can plot a barchart of averages with error bars for my data it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This does kind of seem to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198442/how-to-calculate-mean-median-per-group-in-a-dataframe-in-r which itself is already labeled a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkMiller this is a duplicate of so many duplicates. Not to mention it shows up in many other sites. Even Cross Validated. There are also many versions with `sum` instead of `mean` and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic aggregation question, so the typical starting point should be `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(avgct ~ gregion + lregion, mydf, mean)
  gregion lregion  avgct
1       1       e 1.0465
2       2       e 0.9080
3       3       e 1.1670
4       1       t 1.2250
5       2       t 1.7470
6       3       t 0.6790
```

---

There are, however, several other alternatives, including "dplyr" and "data.table", that may be more appealing in the long run for convenience of syntax and overall efficiency.

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, mean(avgct), by = .(gregion, lregion)]


library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(gregion, lregion) %>% summarise(avgct = mean(avgct))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to calculate standard deviations for those means?

Comment: @opalfruits, sure. The function for standard deviation is `sd`. It's very easy to add other columns using the "data.table" and "dplyr" versions.