# Calculate median per group to fill the gaps

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, median

I have the following dataframe.

```
age      pclass         title
 32        2           Married Man
           3           Married Man
 40        1           Married Women
 47         3          Married Women
           2           Married Women
 5         3           Married Man
```

As you can see "AGE" column can have Missing Values, and while "pclass" column is a integer one, "title" column is a non integer column.

What I have to do is to replace Non Values from Age column with the median of the two other columns (title and pclass).

**Replace non values from Age column by the median of pclass and title**

I don't know if it's possible to calculate the median of two values.

Here is my code, it works but I don't know if it's correct.

```
median(as.numeric(titanic$title),titanic$pclass, na.rm = T)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `as.numeric(string)` is always `NA`. So your median will always be the `pclass`...unless the `title` is a factor and you are just using its levels... but most importantly... Why do you want to do that? It makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Is a problem from a Practice I have to do, its explication is the following one: Complete the missing values ​​now
but with the median of the values ​​according to the variables pclass
and title.

Comment: Oh good. Because age 4 and title Married Woman is quite worrying :/

Comment: it was an example that I put without thinking hahaha

Comment: Please make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: then I guess you're just supposed to take the **median of Age by pclass and title**...

Comment: This example is reproducible, there is no difference between age 4 and 47, the problem I have is, if it's possible to calculate the median as the explication I added in my previous post.

Comment: @Cath Replace the median of the values ​​according to the variables pclass
and title

Comment: @Sotos ? tell me an exact duplicate question, he is calculating ALL the data at the same time(by group) not my question.

Comment: It's at the top of your question. - [This is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198442/how-to-calculate-mean-median-per-group-in-a-dataframe-in-r)