# Median Value for multiple columns

Tags: r, dataset

The question is : What is the median income of those who are not married?
This data set is called Example.Data

My actual set has 3,000 people in it but I shortened it for this example.

```
    Income   Career   Age   Sex  Married
1.   39540    Lawyer   20    F    N
2.   45098    Teacher  65    F    y
3.   54565    Doctor   45    M    y
4.   48356    Teacher  26    M    N
5.   68959    Nurse    32    F    y
6.   98459    Lawyer   34    F    Y
7.   34343    Nurse    49    M    N
```

I need to find the median income of the exact amount of people who aren't married in this data set. I tried making tables like table(c[Example.Data] "Income", "Married", median]) and other variations but I'm so lost on how to get the answer. If it was for one column I know I could just do something like median(Example.data$Income, na.rm=True) but I'm struggling on how I would combine that with the information of them also having to be unmarried to make it work.

Comment: Maybe `median(Example.Data$Income[Example.Data$Married == "N"])`

Comment: Just to expand @AndreWildberg's answer: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198442/how-to-calculate-mean-median-per-group-in-a-dataframe-in-r

Comment: I like `with(Example.Data, by(Example.Data, Married , \(x) median(Income)))`

Comment: Thank you, Andre! I was able to get it with that function.